# protobuf: Difference between new Prototype() and Prototype.Clear()

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-c

for two pieces of codes

```
for (loop) {
    ProtoType instance;
    // do something with instance;
}

/* --------------- */

ProtoType instance;
for (loop) {
    // do something with instance;
    instance.Clear();
}
```

I got core dump with the latter one.
So what's the difference between these two pieces of codes?
What does Prototype.Clear() really do?

Comment: The first version creates a new object each iteration and the second resets and reuses the same object for each iteration.  It's impossible to say why your program is crashing without a [mcve] though.

Comment: thx, and sorry cuz the codebase is really large